# Linux - how to set a default route with 0.0.0.0 as gateway

Tags: linux, ubuntu, routing, route

I have a problem where I need to manually set up a route on Ubuntu 18.04 during the init (ram) process. I cannot use any of the new networking tools, only Busybox is available.

The routing table should looks like this:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens3
172.31.1.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens3
```

The host is a VPS with an IP of 95.xx.xx.xx, so the gateway IP is not on the same network. I can't figure out what command to build the above table with. I get various `SIOCADDDRT` errors with everything I try.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
> route add default gw 172.31.1.1
SIOCADDDRT: Network uncreachable
> route add default gw 172.31.1.1 via 0.0.0.0 
..invalid format
> route add 172.31.1.1 gw 0.0.0.0
SIOCADDDRT: Invalid argument
> route add 0.0.0.0 gw 172.31.1.1
SIOCADDDRT: Network uncreachable
> route add default gw 0.0.0.0
SIOCADDDRT: Invalid argument
```

Is there any way to make this work with Busybox? Or any other way to make it happen inside initram?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not a valid gateway address..

Comment: Setting a gateway which is not on the local network does not work, neither does setting `0.0.0.0` as a gateway. Perhaps if you tell us what it is you're actually trying to achieve we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your desired output in flags, 'G' indicates a gateway, and 'H' represents a host. Hence for the `0.0.0.0` output you are trying to create for the route, its not really used.

To add a host IP to the interface that will generate the same output:

```
ip addr add 172.31.1.1/32 dev ens3
```